# how should i add an object to a private static ArrayList?

Tags: java, class, arraylist, private-members

i have Bank class, with a private static ArrayList that stores all the banks. how can i add every new bank created to it?
i'm not allowed to create any new methods or fields, or change any of the method or constructor parameters.

this is my Bank class:

```
    public class Bank {
        private static ArrayList<Bank> allBanks=new ArrayList<Bank>();
        private String name;

        public Bank(String name) {
             this.name = name;
        }
    public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
```

and this is my Main class:

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
             new Bank("randomBankName");
            }
    }
```

Comment: in your bank class add a method that executes: allBanks.add(...); this method can be static or instance

Comment: as i stated, i'm not allowed to add any new methods

Comment: you can try to use reflection, but why would you even want to do this?

Comment: You have bad class architecture you need to rewrite it!
This code smells... BankList have to be external structure , which passed as parameter in constructor

Comment: there's a uml that i have to match the program with

Comment: Show this uml (part which related to Bank and Banks), is it assessment?
If it is homework use @talex answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in constructor:

```
    public Bank(String name) {
         this.name = name;
         allBanks.add(this);
    }
```

**WARNING** never do it in real project.

Comment: wow, thanks. but why don't you recommend it in a real project?

Comment: @negar.n That is long story. Short version: it make code difficult to maintain.

Comment: @negar.n which line?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say, that you may not change the visibility of fields, so that would be one way to do this: make the `ArrayList` `public`

If you may not do this either, there is a last way, which i'd never do: Reflection.
In most cases, thats really the last way, not recommended!